# Правильный способ отправить скрипт на исполнение

Tags: python

В данный момент отправляю скрипт таким кодом из IDLE

```
import os
os.chdir('C:\MyScript');
import myscript
```

После чего, если он исполнился без ошибок, приходится делать

```
F6 (на клавиатуре)
import os
os.chdir('C:\MyScript');
import myscript
```

Но это выглядит как-то не стройно. Может я что-то не правильно делаю? Может скрипты нужно запускать как-то вроде

```
run myscript
```

или

```
run('C:\MyScript\myscript.py')
```

Comment: Если я вас правильно понимаю, вам нужно выполнить скрипт из IDLE. можно так: `import os os.system("C:\\MyScript\\myscript.py")`

Comment: Да не. В англоязычной версии сайта есть ответ такой: после обычного импорта `import myscript` мы можем загрузить модуль перезапуска `from importlib import reload` и тогда перезагрузить модель командой `myscript = reload(myscript)`

Comment: @ВиталийЯндулов, `import` это не запуск скрипта. Интерпретатору приходится выполнять код при импорте, если он не в `if __name__ == '__main__':`. А при запуске на выполнение `python myscript.py` будет выполнен код, находящийся и в `if __name__ == '__main__':`. Если вам нужно запустить код -- запускайте, а не импортируйте. А лучше подробнее в вопросе объясните какая задача у вас стоит

Comment: У меня в install.py скрипт для раскатки объектов из кучи текстовичков по базе. В самом файле помимо скрипта установки есть несколько определений используемых функций. Для установки я использую import install.